# JQuery Exclude Child element

Tags: jquery, html

I am having dom object with html as below:

```
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Basically I want to remove all child divs not span by jquery.
I tried,

```
myDom.find(".parent").immediateText()
```

But above code return only text not span text that I wanted.
I want the result as below :

```
this is my 11 original text i 23 want
```

Comment: So, only `<span>11</span>` and `<span>23</span>` will be left? Right?

Comment: You are expecting like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4je4our5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".parent > [class^=child]").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find div inside parent class and remove.

```js
$('.parent').find('div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

OR:

```js
   $(document).find('.parent > div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

TRy this

```
$('.parent > div').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***:not(span)*** selector to select everything which is not span.

```js
$('.parent').find(':not(span)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.parent div` Jquery selector to select all the `div` inside element having class `parent` and then use `remove()` to remove them from DOM:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parent div").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    this is my <span>11</span> original text i <span>23</span> want
    <div class="child1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    <div class="child2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the span text:

```
$(".parent span").text();
```

or

```
$(".parent").children("span").text();
```

If you want to select others except the span (and perhaps hide them):

```
$(".parent").find("div") //.hide() or .remove()
```